# In Java how do you replace all instances of a character except the first one?

Tags: java, regex

In Java trying to find a regular expression that will match all instances of a specific character (:) except the first instance, want to replace all instances except first with nothing.

I can do this,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":");
Matcher m =  p.matcher(input);
String output = m.replaceAll("");
```

and there is also m.replaceFirst() but I want to replace everything but first.

Comment: It was a close call between voting to close as 'too localized' or 'not a real question'.  Since you did not ask a question, it was hard to judge if it was 'real'.

Comment: Hint: indexOf, substring

Comment: Okay, Ive added what ive done I know it seems like an easy question but I cant see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For regex replace use match pattern `\G((?!^).*?|[^:]*:.*?):` and as replacement use first group `$1`

*See and test the regex code in Perl [here](http://ideone.com/YXnIJ).*

Comment: Looks like the neatest answer

Answer (score 5):

Naive approach:

```
String[] parts = str.split(":", 2);
str = parts[0] + ":" + parts[1].replaceAll(":", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name ="1_2_3_4_5";
    int index = name.indexOf("_");
    String name1 = name.substring(index+1); 
    name1 = name1.replace("_", "#");

    System.out.println(name.substring(0,index+1)+ name1);
}
```

Comment: String name ="1_2_3_4_5";
    int index = name.indexOf("_");
    System.out.println(name.substring(0,index) + name.substring(index+1).replace("_", "#");

Answer (score 0):

You can use reg ex

```
String str1 = "A:B:C:D:E:F:G:H:I:J:K:L:M";
str1= str1.replaceAll("([:|_].*?):", "$1_");
str1= str1.replaceAll("([:|_].*?):", "$1_");
```

Here I cant modify the regex to have output in first replace itself. Actually first replaceAll do replace ':' with '_' in alternate positions.

Comment: sorry I dont really understand your comment after the regex

Comment: In the above code all ':' are replaced with '_' except first which you were looking for. In order to achieve this you need to call replaceAll function twice. This gives answer to your question. I was just trying to say I was looking for better regular expression which will do this task in first replaceAll itself

Answer (score 0):

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    String start = originalString.substring(0, matcher.end());
    matcher.reset(originalString.substring(matcher.end(), originalString.length()));
    replacedString = start + matcher.replaceAll("");
}
```

Comment: This answer was flagged for length/content by someone. Presumably because it is a code only answer.